# How to pass UIImage to Today Extension in iOS, swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, today-extension

Is there a way to pass UIImage over to Today Extension using NSSharedDefaults in such way? :

```
if let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.example.TodayExtension") {
    // Below line crashes, since .setObject cannot have UIImage as a parameter
    sharedDefaults.setObject(image, forKey: "imageKey") // image = UIImage object
    sharedDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Just share the images to Today extension..Using Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources.. Then store the image name in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the image to a `NSData` object with [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation). Store the `NSData` object in `NSUserDefaults`. In the extension get back the image with [imageWithData(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithData:).